# How to Handle Fetched User's Location from FBSDK IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, fbsdk

i got the user Location using FBSDK. Now I do not know how to seperate the information to get each part of information 
i am printing it in console and this is what get

```
Optional({
id = 110855035610007;
name = "Rawalpindi, Pakistan";
})
```

how do i get "Rawalpindi" and "Pakistan" and store them in some variable
according to [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/location) its returning a Struct i guess so i do not know how to handle that please guide me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you have to create one responseDictionary and then store response in it.

then you can get this name like,

```
 let str = self.responseDic.valueForKey("name") as? String
```

Then you can separate this string like,

```
 let arr : NSArray = str!.componentsSeparatedByString(",") as NSArray
 print(arr.objectAtIndex(0))
 print(arr.objectAtIndex(1))
```

Hope this way you will fix it.